# Отключили клавиатуру через bat файл. Не можем включить

Tags: cmd, bat, реестр

Срочно, Сломали компьютер в школе. Перестала работать клавиатура. Клавиатуру отключили через bat файл с помощью вот такого вот кода :
    `@echo off
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > "keyboard.reg"
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout] >> "keyboard.reg"
echo "Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,7c,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,3b,00,00,00,3c,00,00,00,3d,00,00,00,3e,00,00,00,3f,00,00,00,40,00,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 41,00,00,00,42,00,00,00,43,00,00,00,44,00,00,00,57,00,00,00,58,00,00,00,37,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo e0,00,00,46,00,00,00,45,00,00,00,35,e0,00,00,37,00,00,00,4a,00,00,00,47,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,48,00,00,00,49,00,00,00,4b,00,00,00,4c,00,00,00,4d,00,00,00,4e,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,4f,00,00,00,50,00,00,00,51,00,00,00,1c,e0,00,00,53,00,00,00,52,00,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 4d,e0,00,00,50,e0,00,00,4b,e0,00,00,48,e0,00,00,52,e0,00,00,47,e0,00,00,49,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo e0,00,00,53,e0,00,00,4f,e0,00,00,51,e0,00,00,29,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,03,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,04,00,00,00,05,00,00,00,06,00,00,00,07,00,00,00,08,00,00,00,09,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,0a,00,00,00,0b,00,00,00,0c,00,00,00,0d,00,00,00,0e,00,00,00,0f,00,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 10,00,00,00,11,00,00,00,12,00,00,00,13,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,15,00,00,00,16,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,00,17,00,00,00,18,00,00,00,19,00,00,00,1a,00,00,00,1b,00,00,00,2b,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,3a,00,00,00,1e,00,00,00,1f,00,00,00,20,00,00,00,21,00,00,00,22,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,23,00,00,00,24,00,00,00,25,00,00,00,26,00,00,00,27,00,00,00,28,00,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 1c,00,00,00,2a,00,00,00,2c,00,00,00,2d,00,00,00,2e,00,00,00,2f,00,00,00,30,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,00,31,00,00,00,32,00,00,00,33,00,00,00,34,00,00,00,35,00,00,00,36,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,1d,00,00,00,5b,e0,00,00,38,00,00,00,39,00,00,00,38,e0,00,00,5c,e0,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,5d,e0,00,00,1d,e0,00,00,5f,e0,00,00,5e,e0,00,00,22,e0,00,00,24,e0,00,00,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 10,e0,00,00,19,e0,00,00,30,e0,00,00,2e,e0,00,00,2c,e0,00,00,20,e0,00,00,6a,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo e0,00,00,69,e0,00,00,68,e0,00,00,67,e0,00,00,42,e0,00,00,6c,e0,00,00,6d,e0,\ >> "keyboard.reg"
echo 00,00,66,e0,00,00,6b,e0,00,00,21,e0,00,00,00,00 >> "keyboard.reg"
start keyboard.reg`

Comment: Вы учитель информатики?

Comment: Об методе отката легко догадаться по приведенному вами коду :) пионэрам 2 поставьте, надо было ещё и мышь вам отключить :) чтоб обратно нечем было вернуть..  :)

Comment: Я не учитель, просто хотел посмеятся))) Мышь тоже думал отключить))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Откройте RegEdit и удалите параметр Scancode Map из HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Keyboard Layout. Перезагрузитесь